# The new co-ordinates of a point $(4,5)$ when the origin is shifted to the point $(1,-2)$ are:

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

The new co-ordinates of a point $(4,5)$ when the origin is shifted to the point $(1,-2)$ are:

$1$. $(5,3)$

$2$. $(3,5)$

$3$. $(3,7)$

$4$. None.

My Attempt:

$$\#1$$
 The origin is shifted to the right by $1$unit (right means positive $x$). The point is thus shifted identically, thus the first coordinate of your new point is $5$.

The origin is also shifted down by $2$ units (down means negative $y$). The point goes similarly, so the second coordinate is $3$.

Result is, thus, $(5, 3)$.

$$\#2$$

Let the new origin be $(h,k)=(1,-2)$ and $(x,y)=(4,5)$ be the given point.

Therefore the new co-ordinates $(X,Y)$

$$x=X+h$$
$$4=X+1$$
$$X=3$$

$$y=Y+k$$
$$5=Y-2$$
$$Y=7$$

So, the result is $(X,Y)=(3,7)$.

I got two different answers. Which one is correct?

Comment: Number 2 is correct.

Comment: The second, simply because of *Chasles' relation*: if $\Omega$ is the new origin, $\overrightarrow{\Omega M}=\overrightarrow{O M}-\overrightarrow{O\Omega}$.

Comment: @Bernard, Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The coordinates of , $\overrightarrow{\Omega M}$ are $X$ and and $Y$, those of $\overrightarrow{O M}$ are $x$ and $y$; and this vector relation remains value after projections on each of the axes, so trivially $X=x-h$ and $Y=y-k$. Isn't is it clear?

Comment: @Bernard, Isn't it same what I did in $#2#$??

Comment: It is. I only systematised in a general formula which is easy to remember.